# BackTrack doesn't install on VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox, debian, backtrack

BackTrack doesn't seem to be installing with my VirtualBox.

I am running VirtualBox on Mac OS X 10.7.5 and have downloaded GNOME BackTrack. When I try to install it, it just stops in shell. I have linked the image of where it stops.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enter: `startx`. This will launch the desktop environment.